# Create a new activity doesn't work on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i just started learning to develop android apps through a tutorial on the internet and when i was trying to create a new activity it said after selecting the java folder select com.****.**** and then right click go to new select activity and select the activity you want , however when i do this on my android studio my Android studio just stops loading for about 40 seconds and then it does nothing , it doesn't show an error it doesn't do anything it just stops loading and then it resumes normally as if i didn't give it any create commands . 
my android studio version is 1.2.2 
any help ?

Comment: update to android studio version 1.5

Comment: i will try to update it now

Comment: @Bhargav thank you very much that fixed my problem , i tried to update it at first and that didnt work so uninstalled it downloaded the 1.5 manually since it wont auto update and threw an error and installed it manually and it fixed it , thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update to android studio version 1.5

Answer (score 0):

What JDK are you using? The recommended one is the oracle jdk version 7.

Comment: using the command prompt to find the java version i get this :
java version = "1.8.0_60"